# Executando comandos PHP salvo no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como faço para salvar e executar códigos PHP salvo no meu banco MySQL. Eu já criei uma estrutura básica para o cadastro de instruções. A minha dúvida é sobre como manipular o uso destes códigos.
Por exemplo, criei uma tabela 'Instrucoes', contendo os campos (ID, título, instruções). Qual é a maneira mais adequada de chamar essas instruções?

Comment: PHP não é compilado. É uma linguagem de script.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer executar comandos salvos no banco, para isto é só usar a função `eval()` que recebe uma *string* como parâmetro e a executa como código *PHP*

```
$foo = "bar";
eval("echo $foo");
```

Comment: Só deve ter cuidado com o que executa em `eval`

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma estudada nesta função.. Aproveitando a pergunta, é possível eu bloquear o uso de determinadas palavras, de modo que elas não sejam interpretadas? exemplo: 'include'